# Use of unresolved identifier 'url'

Tags: swift, swift3, dropbox-api

I'm completely new to API's, and am following this tutorial on appcoda
https://www.appcoda.com/dropbox-api-tutorial/

It's been going very smoothly, but I've run into a problem, and given that I'm a novice, I don't have the first clue with how to fix it.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let appKey = "n00nzv68gtxk6c9"      // Set your own app key value here.
        let appSecret = "itumv0icksr7yj6"   // Set your own app secret value here.

        let dropboxSession = DBSession(appKey: appKey, appSecret: appSecret, root: kDBRootDropbox)
        DBSession.setShared(dropboxSession)

        return true

        if DBSession.sharedSession().handleOpenURL(url) {
            if DBSession.shared().isLinked() {
                NotificationCenter.defaultCenter.postNotificationName("didLinkToDropboxAccountNotification", object: nil)
                return true
            }
        }

        return false

    }
```

The problem is in the line

```
if DBSession.sharedSession().handleOpenURL(url) {
```

where I get the error

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'url'
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: You either need to properly declare and initialize a variable named `url` before you attempt to use it or you need to replace `url` with the another `URL` type variable.

Comment: What type should it be?

Comment: Also note that the `if DBSession...` block is in a completely different delegate method than the one you put in.

Comment: *"What type should it be?"* - go to the documentation page for the `DBSession` class and look at the information for the `handleOpenURL` method. It will tell you what type it should be.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't get what you mean: "Also note that the if DBSession... block is in a completely different delegate method than the one you put in"

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the tutorial you linked to. You need to put the code in the proper place just like in the tutorial.

Comment: @rmaddy are you sure? Which method should it be in? Thank you for your help, btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131104/discussion-between-theodore-k-and-rmaddy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the tutorial, you need to use the correct delegate method within AppDelegate.swift

```
// handle custom application schemes
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if DBSession.sharedSession().handleOpenURL(url) {
        print("Url defined as \( url)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a dumb mistake